# Python Numpy repeating an arange array

Tags: arrays, numpy, repeat, numpy-ndarray

so say I do this

```
x = np.arange(0, 3)
```

which gives

```
array([0, 1, 2])
```

but what can I do like

```
x = np.arange(0, 3)*repeat(N=3)times
```

to get

```
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

EDIT: Refer to hpaulj's answer. It is frankly better.

The simplest way is to convert back into a list and use:

```
list(np.arange(0,3))*3
```

Which gives:

```
>> [0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2]
```

Or if you want it as a `numpy` array:

```
np.array(list(np.arange(0,3))*3)
```

Which gives:

```
>> array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: I thought this way was easier than using a `for` loop.

Comment: how do I repeat a different number of times? for example
a = np.arange(4) => 0,1,2,3
np.magic_function(a, [4,3,2]) => 0,1,2,3,0,1,2,0,1

Answer (score 15):

I've seen several recent questions about `resize`.  It isn't used often, but here's one case where it does just what you want:

```
In [66]: np.resize(np.arange(3),3*3)
Out[66]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

There are many other ways of doing this.

```
In [67]: np.tile(np.arange(3),3)
Out[67]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
In [68]: (np.arange(3)+np.zeros((3,1),int)).ravel()
Out[68]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

`np.repeat` doesn't repeat in the way we want

```
In [70]: np.repeat(np.arange(3),3)
Out[70]: array([0, 0, 0, 1, 1, 1, 2, 2, 2])
```

but even that can be reworked (this is a bit advanced):

```
In [73]: np.repeat(np.arange(3),3).reshape(3,3,order='F').ravel()
Out[73]: array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

Comment: great answer but I accepted the other answer as you are way to good at programming in python and the other guy needs some answers accepted to catch up on your exceptional stats! But thanks for the helpful answer :-)

Comment: I think that `resize` is the exact answer to the original question

Comment: @RunnerBean thanks for the score, but probs should've given it to hpaulj. That way other people get to know the best answer too!

Answer (score 5):

how about this one?

```
arr = np.arange(3)
res = np.hstack((arr, ) * 3)
```

**Output**

```
array([0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2, 0, 1, 2])
```

Not much overhead I would say.